# python lazy translation - add line break to translation string

Tags: python, django, newline, translation

How do I add line breaks to a lazy translation? I have searched [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#), SO & Google, but no information is found.

I have my lazy translation working with multiline below, but the newline / line breaks are rendered to the screen.

```
messages.success(
    request,
    _("If the e-mail address has been registered, you'll receive an e-mail with instructions."
    "/n/n"
    "If you don't receive this e-mail, check your spam e-mail folder or contact us for assistance."))
```

I have also tried < b r / >, and backslash n but these are not rendered as new lines on the django template screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should use backslash `\n` for newline symbol.

Note that `\n` symbol is the regular whitespace and on HTML page it is looks like simple space.  If you want to show multi-line message then you should use `<br />` tags and make the message "safe":

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

messages.success(request,
        mark_safe("If the e-mail address has been registered ..."
                  "<br /><br />"
                  "If you don't receive this e-mail, check your spam ...."))
```

Comment: catavan, thanks but the backslash n does not work for the code. Nothing is display and no new line is displayed. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is display"?  It should display your message as is, with two new lines which are regular whitespaces in HTML.

Comment: I added example of HTML multi-line message to the answer.

Comment: the example added by catavan renders the html line breaks to the screen as  `<br /><br />` - not as actual line breaks. I have tried this with and without lazy translation - and yes I am importing **mark_safe**.

Comment: How do you render messages in html?  I tested this code with django admin and it works as expected.